# Same Kinesis Consumer running on multiple EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl

I have multiple instances of EC2 running for a same microservice, which has a Kinesis consumer running(with KCL).

My question is, when Kinesis stream gets a new event, since all consumers are polling, will the same event be consumed by consumers of all instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event will be consumed only by one consumer

Answer (score 2):

KCL is designed so that each shard is processed by only one worker - the built-in lease mechanism is the key to providing this functionality.

While **under normal circumstances each consumer will only receive messages for the shards it owns the lease for**, there are some edge cases (typically caused by when connections timeout/break or hosts die/stop responding) worth considering that can result in double-processing of a message from the stream.

As a concrete example: If a worker fails to renew a lease (typically caused by a connectivity issue between the worker host and DynamoDB), it's possible another worker will acquire that lease and start processing while the original worker is still doing work